# On change event not working in two elements

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events, filereader

I have an HTML markup element

```
<div class="icon-upload">
  <div class="icon-edit">
    <input type='file' id="icoUpload" onchange="getURL(this)" class="icoUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"/>
    <label for="icoUpload"></label>
</div>
<div class="icon-preview">
    <div id="icoPreview" style="background-image: url(assets/img/dash/Add-icon.png);">
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS code is this

```
function getURL(input) {
    if (input && input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            input.parentElement
                 .nextElementSibling
                 .firstChild
                 .nextElementSibling
                 .style
                 .backgroundImage = 'url('+e.target.result +')';
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

So basically what it does is take the input type file's image URL and shows a preview.
It is working perfectly fine.

Now when I add another element of class .icon-upload by simply duplicating, onchange attribute on the second element is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you use a different ID for the new input.

Comment: Did you press enter in the input? onchange doesn't fire without that.

Comment: @Anonymous that shouldn't affect the JavaScript. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @blaumeise20 as you can see I have a label which render edit icon by clicking on that it opt for file choose. and input file is display none. as i said earlier it works fine for first element.

Comment: It could be blocking for security reasons, maybe worth checking.

Comment: working fine check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5mvs7zch/)